# How to add button overLay in Video Tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html5-video

I appended a div within `video` tag and used following CSS but it is not working. I already incorported javascript to play/stop video on click. I want to show a button in the middle of player. Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/trixta/VvmmC/)

```
#player_buttons
{
    width: 128px;
    height: 128px;
    z-index: 99;
    background: url('http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iconslandplayer/PNG/64x64/CircleBlue/Play1Pressed.png') center center no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can/should place content inside a video-element other than video-sources unless you want that content displayed in browsers that do not support the video-tag. Taken from the specs:

> Content may be provided inside the video element; it is intended for
>   older Web browsers which do not support video, so that legacy video
>   plugins can be tried, or to show text to the users of these older
>   browsers informing them of how to access the video contents

http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/video.html#video

But by wrapping the video element with a container and appending the overlay-div to that container, you can stack them via **position:absolute** and **z-index**.

You can see the example here: http://jsfiddle.net/vtrzmf92/

Updated HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <video src="#" width="800" height="600"></video>
    <div class="player-buttons"></div>
</div>
```

Updated CSS:

```
.container{
    position: relative;
}

.container>.player-buttons{
    background: url('http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iconslandplayer/PNG/64x64/CircleBlue/Play1Pressed.png') center center no-repeat;
    height: 128px;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -64px 0 0 -64px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 128px;
    z-index: 1; 
}
```